# Bigquery error: 400 No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have deployed my webapp on Google Cloud Bigquery, when I query the data I get an error `"400 No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATE, STRING, STRING. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) at [2:38]"`. Here is my sql:

```
"""SELECT 
   Record_Start_Time, Generator_Power 
FROM 
   Furnace.FurnaceData
WHERE 
   Record_Start_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-01-21")
AND 
  TIMESTAMP("2018-07-21") 
ORDER BY Record_Start_Time
LIMIT 100""".format(request.form['start'],request.form['end'])
```

Comment: Please check your arguments you are passing in the query and the one in the table

Comment: Unless `FurnaceData` is a view, that query cannot generate that error.  The `BETWEEN` clearly has `TIMESTAMP`s for the range operands.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean by "FurnaceData is a view", and where can I check that?

Comment: @Prince you can have a look at the documentation about [Views in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro). In order to check if you are querying a table or a view, you can go to the BigQuery UI and check the icon next to the *table*. A green icon means this is a View; a blue icon means this is a Table. Additionally, if you click on them, it will show a new screen with the message "View Details" or "Table Details".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the error message you are getting (which, I agree with the comments in your question, is strange and I suspect does not correspond to this specific query), it looks like the field `Record_Start_Time` is of type `DATE`, while in the `BETWEEN` operator you are using `TIMESTAMP` values instead.

The way you should understand the error message you are getting, is the following:

```
[...] operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATE, STRING, STRING. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY)
```

This error means that the supported signature for the `BETWEEN` operator is `field BETWEEN a AND b`, where `field`, `a` and `b` should be of the same type (*ANY*). Additionally, the error message tells you that you are doing the following: `_DATE_ BETWEEN _STRING_ AND _STRING_`, i.e. you are trying to compare a `DATE` type with a `STRING` type. This looks strange because `TIMESTAMP("2018-01-21")` is of `TIMESTAMP` type and not `STRING`, but I would say that maybe you tried in the past running a query like `WHERE Record_Start_Time BETWEEN "2018-01-21" AND "2018-07-21"`, and the error message you shared is the one corresponding to that query. For the query you shared, the error message should be:

```
400 No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) at [2:38]
```

---

Long story short, confirm that the `Record_Start_Time` field is of `DATE` type and being that the case, change your `WHERE` clause to the following:

```
WHERE 
   Record_Start_Time BETWEEN DATE("2018-01-21")
AND 
  DATE("2018-07-21")
```

Comment: thank you for explanation. You are right on the type of error, I was getting two different errors. It is fixed now. I changed the type from (DATE) to (TIMESTAMP) on my data file on BigQuery, and it works nicely now. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Consider upvoting the answer if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
where ((data_resultado between '2023-10-20' AND '2023-10-30') OR (data_resultado between'2023-10-25' AND '2023-11-05'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply