# bigrquery - Error: No matching signature for operator - for argument types: DATE, FLOAT64

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr, bigrquery

When `filter()`ing by date, and using a function to provide that date, I see an expected error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigrquery)

table1 %>% 
  filter(date > as.character(today() - 730)) %>% 
  tally()

# Error: No matching signature for operator - for argument types: DATE, FLOAT64. 
Supported signatures: INT64 - INT64; NUMERIC - NUMERIC; FLOAT64 - FLOAT64 at [29:29] [invalidQuery]
```

but when the date is provided as a string it works fine

```
table1 %>%
  filter(date > '2018-04-11') %>% 
  tally()

#          n
#      <int>
#  623451234
```

I can confirm `as.character(today() - 730)` and `'2018-04-11'` are the same

```
> identical(as.character(today() - 730), '2018-04-11')
[1] TRUE
```

The following workaround is okay, but becomes cluttered for larger code bases:

```
date_from <- as.character(today() - 730)

table1 %>% 
  filter(date > date_from) %>% 
  tally()
```

#### Question

Why do we see an error when a date is provided to `filter()` via a function like `as.character(today() - 730)`, but not when the date is provided by a string?

#### Notes

- similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214576/bigquery-error-400-no-matching-signature-for-operator-between-for-argument-type)
- I tried replacing `as.character(today() - 730)` with `as.Date(today() - 730)` and got exactly the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged this with `dbplyr` though there is no mention of it in your question. If you are using `dbplyr` then the issue is due to how `dbplyr` translates from R to the database language (bigquery in your case).

`dbplyr` has a series of in-built translations that do the conversion (e.g. `filter` gets tranlated to `WHERE` clauses). These translations are able to look up values from variables as per your example:

```r
date_from <- as.character(today() - 730)
table1 %>% filter(date > date_from)
```

But can not tell for sub-functions whether to evaluate, translate, or leave as-is. Hence according to [this](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html) documentation dbplyr leaves any 'unknown' functions as-is. This means that

```r
table1 %>% filter(date > as.character(today() - 730))
```

probably gets translated to something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE date > as.character(today() - 730)
```

which causes an error as this is not valid syntax for the database.

You can check the translation by using `show_query()`:

```r
table1 %>% filter(date > as.character(today() - 730)) %>% show_query()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211123/function-that-composes-functions-with-existing-sql-translations-in-dbplyr) asks about a very similar problem - the translations are defined for the functions they are using, but not for the custom function that acts as a wrapper. Being able to define custom translations would solve both questions but this does not appear possible at present.

There are two work arounds:

1. From the [dbplyr documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/dbplyr.pdf) you can use `sql()` to insert a raw SQL string (that will not be translated).
2. You can write your own functions that return custom table definitions. See the "Creating custom functions" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537458/how-to-pipe-sql-into-rs-dplyr).